# How to return all fields instead of just id and count after sortByCount operation in Mongodb/Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I need to do sortByCount and return all the fields instead of just _id and count.

sortByCount returns:

```
    { "_id" : "1", "count" : 4 }
    { "_id" : "2", "count" : 3 }
    { "_id" : "3", "count" : 2 }
    { "_id" : "4", "count" : 2 }
    { "_id" : "5", "count" : 1 }
```

But, I need a complete document like below:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "title": "The Pillars of Society",
    "artist": "Grosz",
    "year": 1926,
    "tags": ["painting", "satire", "Expressionism", "caricature"]
} {
    "_id": 2,
    "title": "Melancholy III",
    "artist": "Munch",
    "year": 1902,
    "tags": ["woodcut", "Expressionism"]
} {
    "_id": 3,
    "title": "Dancer",
    "artist": "Miro",
    "year": 1925,
    "tags": ["oil", "Surrealism", "painting"]
} {
    "_id": 4,
    "title": "The Great Wave off Kanagawa",
    "artist": "Hokusai",
    "tags": ["woodblock", "ukiyo-e"]
} {
    "_id": 5,
    "title": "The Persistence of Memory",
    "artist": "Dali",
    "year": 1931,
    "tags": ["Surrealism", "painting", "oil"]
}
```

Is there any way to replace root after sortByCount? In Java, I don't see any push method after sortByCount

Comment: this is the **expected output vs actual output**, how was you trying to read the document **(effort)**?

Comment: Yes, actual output which sortByCount returns is a document with _id and count fields. I need a complete document

Comment: can you post *model*, *fetching strategy* i.e. the *code involved in this process?*

Comment: please read this article before editing https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

$sortByCount is essentially a combination of $group followed by $sort on count field of group stage. If you really want the entire documents, you can try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "id": "$_id"
      },
      "count": {
        $sum: 1
      },
      "reqItems": {
        $push: {
          "title": "$title",
          "artist": "$artist"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      count: -1
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GwLsWPAqW7a)